# Python regex find nth number

Tags: python, regex, match

For learning purposes I am doing some regex challenges from *CodeFights*. Now they have very specific rules in what to change to get the correct result. I solved the puzzle using a different method and I can't wrap my head around how they want me to do it.

**Q:** return the nth number of a giving string not leaded by zero's

**Example**

```
# I can only change ... to solve it
# def nthNumber_asked(s, n):
#    pattern = ...
#    return re.match(pattern, s).group(1)

# How I solved it
def nthNumber_mine(s, n):
    return re.findall(r'(0*)([0-9]+)', s)[n-1][1]

s1 = "8one 003number 201numbers li-000233le number444"
s2 = "LaS003920tP3rEt4t04Yte0023s3t"

print(nthNumber_mine(s1, 4)) # Expected outcome = 233
print(nthNumber_mine(s2, 4)) # Expected outcome = 4
```

Comment: Whats the pattern definition ?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: you want the last number or highest number among all

Comment: I want the nth number, ie. The (4th) number in my example in a given string

Comment: Is this an online challenge somewhere, so we can test our solutions there?

Comment: Yes this is a challenge from codefights https://codefights.com/arcade/code-arcade/regular-hell/Rqtm4Yv8GhHYXJYPY

Comment: @Ludisposed Ah, darn, I registered but they still want me to solve the earlier problems first...

Comment: @StefanPochmann That is true and forgot to mention it, you should try it out sometimes though. I'm having a lot of fun on there :)

Comment: @Ludisposed How many problems do I need to solve to get to this one? If it's not many, I might just do it.

Comment: `\D*(?:\d+\D+){3}0*(\d+)` should work fine for the samples given, though it's not perfect (when handling weird zero cases) - e.g. what should happen if one of the numbers 1 to 3 is zero only or the expected number is zero only.

Comment: @SebastianProske Yes that is it! Thank you very much, if you could maybe explain the proces in an awnser I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fullfil the requirements you can use this regex:

```
def nthNumber_asked(s, n):
    pattern = "\D*(?:\d+\D+){" + str(n-1) + "}0*(\d+)"
    return re.match(pattern, s).group(1)
```

First I look for a non-digit, then n-1 groups of digits + non-digits (non-capturing) and then finally I ignore all zeros, and catch the rest of the number. However, ignoring all zeros is a bad idea if there is a number that is only zeros, as that will be ignored. I would prefer to include the zeros in the number. Otherwise a more complex pattern with look-ahead is probably needed.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
def nthNumber_mine(s, n):
    return re.search(r'(?:\d+.+?){%d}0*(\d+)' % (n-1), s).group(1)
```

`(?:\d+\D+?){%d}` matches at least 1 digit followed by at least 0 other chars, for n-1 times. Then at least 0 zeroes are matched, then at least a digit is matched (that is what you are looking for).

Comment: You might want to use `\D+` instead of `.*?` for cases with less than n numbers present.

Comment: @Ludisposed Sure, just add `\D*` at the beginning of the regex. But why?

Comment: @horcrux Thank you for your help.. sorry if I was being unclear but the requirements was using re.match instead of search